# Disable scroll of an iframe in Safari in iOS

Tags: css, iframe, scroll, mobile-safari

If I have an iframe inside a webpage, even if it has no overflowing content (so it doesn't show any scrollbars in any platforms) and while not having any scrollbars just to make things clear for Safari I add

- `scrolling='off'` to the iframe
- `overflow: hidden` to its CSS
- `overflow: hidden` to the html and body of the page that loads in the iframe
- `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;` to html and body of the page that loads in the iframe too (to disable momentum scrolling)
- event listeners for `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` that binds those events of the iframe to `e => e.preventDefault()`

With all that, when I touch the part of the screen that's on top of the iframe and move my finger, instead of scrolling the parent page (cause I supposedly disabled all kinds of scrolling in the iframe) it tries to scroll the iframe with the momentum scroll.

So for example if I have `<div>Some Text</div>` above the iframe and my parent page is long enough to have scroll bars, if I scroll the page by touching content out of iframe, my main page scrolls as it's supposed to.

Now assume I scroll down the page so that `Some Text` is not visible, and then I touch the iframe and move my finger down to see `Some Text` again (cause it's supposed to not be scrollable and ignore all scroll/touch events and pass it to its parent, just like how chrome does it) instead of seeing `Some Text` I see a blank screen on top of the page (momentum scroll effect when there's no content above, because it's trying to scroll the inner iframe and there's no content above the scroll area of the inner iframe).

If I do the same thing by touching somewhere out of the iframe, I see `Some Text` as expected. I want this iframe to behave like a normal unscrollable div.

I want it to not be scrollable but I don't know how to communicate this requirement to Safari. Chrome didn't need any of the above mentioned things, just cause the iframe didn't have any content overflowing, everything worked as expected in Chrome without doing anything, but for some reason Safari insists on assuming that this iframe needs to be scrollable.

- Is there any way to disable scrolling for an iframe completely?
- Is there any way to disable vertical scrolling for an iframe completely while preserving horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem. I would remove all of that, and start over.

My solution:
The underlying page is index2.html, and then on top of it I have index.aspx which has this style attribute:

```
.resp-container { 
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 70.25%;
    height: 900px;
}
```

index2.html does not have this class in it, but index.aspx uses this class:

```
    <iframe id="myIframe" class="resp-iframe" src="/index2.html"></iframe>
```

Note: the underlying html height must be larger than the container it's in, because...idk why, but if it's smaller or the same size, it doesn't work.

You can also turn off scrolling via javascript in a couple of ways:

- `document.getElementById("myIframe").setAttribute("scrolling", "no");`
- `document.getElementById("myIframe").style.overflow="hidden";`